# How the kernel works in a LCF theorem prover

Tags: programming-languages, automated-theorem-proving

I heard that there is some mechanism in LCF-based theorem provers that only allows some functions to create values of type theorem. I believe these are based on abstract data types.

Could someone sketch in pseudo-code how does this work? (in case the above is correct)

Comment: Are you familiar with abstract data types from the ML family of languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts and code from the kernel (file thm.ML in Isabelle/Pure) from Isabelle:

```
abstype thm = Thm of
 deriv *                        (*derivation*)
 {cert: Context.certificate,    (*background theory certificate*)
  tags: Properties.T,           (*additional annotations/comments*)
  maxidx: int,                  (*maximum index of any Var or TVar*)
  shyps: sort Ord_List.T,       (*sort hypotheses*)
  hyps: term Ord_List.T,        (*hypotheses*)
  tpairs: (term * term) list,   (*flex-flex pairs*)
  prop: term}                   (*conclusion*)
and deriv = Deriv of
 {promises: (serial * thm future) Ord_List.T,
  body: Proofterm.proof_body}
with
```

Also here is a quotation of from Paulson book on ML. About abstract datatypes he says:

> A modular structure makes a program easier to understand. Better still, the
>   modules ought to serve as interchangeable parts: replacing one module by an
>   improved version should not require changing the rest of the. program. Standard
>   ml's abstract types and functors can help us meet this objective too.
>   A module may reveal its internal details. When the module is replaced, other
>   parts of the program that depend upon such details will fail. ML provides several
>   ways of declaring an abstract type and related operations, while hiding the type's
>   representation.

So you cannot instantiate an abstract datatype you can use it (its fields + functions). The matter on how you implement this feature is very of dependent of the language. If you want to do it in the lambda-calculus, there should be something like that in Benjamin Pierce's TAPL book on the later chapters.

A nice reference for this is also [here](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2017.0872).

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, this was chapter 5 or 6 of John Harrison's *Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning*.

Jon Sterling wrote some [notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15317-f17/recitations/recitation7.pdf) for a recitation a year or two back, specifically for an LCF prover using sequent calculus.

Comment: thank you for sharing, those are very good references